# Add multiple reference emails to mailchimp in WordPress or PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I need to add multiple reference emails to MailChimp using PHP. At the moment, a referrer can add only one record into MailChimp at a time. I want it to be multiple email records sent at once to MailChimp, in case the user has more than one email to refer.

I am fine if we can hit MailChimp API one at a time while looping through the emails records.

Comment: Fixes MailChimp capitalization, as seen in their website. And updates a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin that loop through the Mailchimp add record API and add the records to Mailchimp. Goal achieved.